# Как называется эта конструкция?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как называется эта конструкция в JS?

```
 this.primeCost = {
    leasing: 0.45,  
    buyed: 0.25     
};
```

Comment: да по разному: можно считать ассоциативным массивом, структурой, объектом и т.д.

Comment: @Zhihar Спасибо!!! То что нужно!

Comment: В javascript - это называется объектом

Answer (score 2):

Обращение к [объекту](https://learn.javascript.ru/object) в рамках некоторого скоупа по указателю [this](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods). В данном примере это создание, присваивание нового объекта по ссылке. Необходимо заметить что `this` в `JavaScript` себя ведет не так как в других языках программирования, по этому я и написал в первом предложении - "в рамках некоторого скоупа".

Если написал что не так, не серчайте, критика приветствуется !

Comment: Спасибо, а сам объект в данном случае это массив или что? Не встречал такой инициализации, название не знаю...

Comment: @WebFR в данном случае это объект с двумя свойствами - leasing и buyed

Comment: @WebFR для примера может быть массив из таких объектов - https://jsfiddle.net/nmx6oq2r/